# Data is not getting fetched by id in controller but it is getting fetched in jsp that calls controller

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a wierd problem in an application. I pass an id of table row from jsp to servlet. On jsp load I tried to fetch data by id and print in log file. It is getting printed.

But when on submit I pass that id to controller and try to fetch same data with passed id it is not finding anything and returning null. data exists in database I have queried the database and found the data. We are using mysql version 5.6.51.

And this issue is intermitent. Some time only this occurs most of the time it is able to retrieve data from database in controller.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information, like the relevant part of your code and reproduction steps?

Comment: Do you close everything (Connection/PreparedStatement/ResultSet)? Open things is general the problem for intermittent failures.

Comment: Please show your code and describe what debug steps you took to isolate the error.

Comment: We had 2 pages, on 1st page submit data stored in db and then retrieve id and pass it to jsp and then on submit of that jsp id is sent to controller and then we are retrieveing data from that id. in latter part of code we generate new id if that id don't found and delete previous id. We had print logs just after  data gets stored in db by retrieveing it and in 2nd jsp we also retrieved the data by id but onsubmit when it reaches controller it is not able to retrieve data by id. then next time after some validation when delete method gets called we retrieved the data by idand it gets retrieved.

Comment: I don't see how we can help here with only your description and no code. Try to debug your code and if this is not possible because the bug is not reproducible you can only add extensive logging and check the relevant parts of your code for possible bugs like forgotten transaction commits, unclosed files, unlogged exceptions etc.

Comment: If the error comes only sporadic maybe it is a concurrency issue. E.g. all access to objects stored in the servlet session should be threadsafe. But this is only guessing.

Comment: I have checked all statements and connections and resultsets are closed. But I don't understand threadsafe servlet session if something relates to that is faulty then we should not retrieve id or other user order id. But that is not the case.